# How to get XPATH of element in div. Python selenium

Tags: python, html, css, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have **python** code and I need it to **pass divs** and get **text** from each div.

I have a **loop**, which looks like:

```
for i in range(friends_count):
    found = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*=friends_list_bl]>div")))
```

*(found is the highlighted div)*

(It pass each div, I`ll show you only one)

Here you see **one** div (highlighted) of the list of divs. I need to take "Гимназия № 82" from here. *(Where "class=friends_field")*.
[image: Here you see one div (highlighted) of the list of divs]

I also have a **similar code** but it takes **names** from the **divs**. It looks like:

```
name = found[i].find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "AvatarRich__img").get_attribute("alt")
```

But I can't think of any way to implement it with this.

**P.S: I just need to make XPATH from the highest div on the screenshot, to the very bottom**

Can anyone solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question by using:

```
a = found.text
if (needed_text in a.split("\n"):
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you question. If you went to take the div from the bottom using as reference the top div you can use an XPATH as follows:

```py
for i in range(friends_count):
    found = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'friends_list_bl' )]//div[contains(@class, 'friends_field')]")))
```

Comment: Sorry for my incomprehensible question. I updated my question in a more understandable form. Your answer is not working. It returns me the same that I also can get with a "similar code" I showed in my question.

Comment: This could should provide you in `found` with the div that contains `Гимназия № 82`. Is not that what you want?

Comment: This provides me another data which is in another div

Comment: Then if you want the content of the div you have to call `found.text`

Comment: I want the content of the specific div, but I cant get the XPATH to this div